# Concentration of empirical measure under Prokhorov distance

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, concentration-of-measure, empirical-processes

For any two probability measures $\mu,\nu$ over $\mathbb{R}^d$, the Prokhorov distance is defined to be
$$d_P(\mu,\nu)=\inf\{\epsilon:\mu(A)\le \nu(A^{\epsilon})+\epsilon\text{ and }\nu(A)\le\mu(A^{\epsilon})+\epsilon~\text{for all Borel set }A\subset\mathbb{R}^d\},$$
where $A^{\epsilon}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:\forall y\in A,~||x-y||_2\le\epsilon\}$.

Suppose we have $i.i.d.$ samples $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ from some probability measure $\mu$. The empirical measure is defined to be
$$\hat{\mu}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{X_i},$$
where $\delta_{X_i}$ is Dirac measure on $X_i$.

My question is: for any $\epsilon>0$ do we have concentration inequality
$$\mathrm{Pr}[d_P(\hat{\mu}_n,\mu)\ge \epsilon]\le C(\epsilon, n)$$
where $C(\epsilon, n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and depends only on $\epsilon$ and $n$.

Note that, similar concentration ineqaulity holds for the Komogrov-Smirnov distance by the [DKW-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality). But KS-distance is not consistent with weak convergence. I'm wondering whether similar result hold for the Prokhorov distance.

Answer (score 1):

By the law of large numbers,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(X_{i}) \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x) \, \mu(dx) \quad \text{a.s. if} \, \, f \in BC(\mathbb{R}^{d})
\end{equation*}
Thus, since $BC(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is separable, $\hat{\mu}_{n} \to \mu$ almost surely.

This implies, in particular, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\{d_{P}(\hat{\mu}_{n},\mu) \geq \epsilon\} = 0$ for each $\epsilon > 0$.  Indeed, we know that $d_{P}(\hat{\mu}_{n},\mu) \to 0$ almost surely, and almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

You were looking for a $C(\epsilon,n)$ depending only on $\epsilon$ and $n$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} C(\epsilon,n) = 0$.  I found a $C(\epsilon,n,\mu)$.  My best guess is this is the best one can do without imposing additional assumptions on $\mu$.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer. Yes, I also think a unifrom convergence may not exists without a  continuity assumption.  But I can't find a counterexample.